# Require more reviews for First Posts queue

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow, review, suggested-edits

In the actual review system I find that many post or at least first questions are not in the list, but their are not good question, they need  not just to improve the formatting, but to add the tag of the programming language, or point that it is incomplete, for example: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21859319/2886003) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21859770/using-apportable-to-port-to-android-in-portrait-view#21859770).

I couldn't find a protocol or manual to review the first post, or a way to check if it is really reviewed and not just, "No Action Needed" when it really needs some improvements. [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149621/247279) you can check that it is a concern of the community.

What I propose is to review each first post/question at least twice. Or at least give guidelines to mark as checked before being able to skip or mark it as no action needed.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no clue what you are trying to ask.  Are you asking why posts are only reviewed once and proposing to allow more users to review a single post?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps now it is more clear. No I am proposing that the actual users who can review, review a post and another person review the same post already reviewed to really check if it is a good question/answer or it is wall tagged/formatted, it doesn't belong to SO...

Comment: Reviews in First Posts and Late Answers are carefully limited to ensure only 1 person reviews each post.  This is because voting is enabled in the posts and they do not want too much voting to come from the review queues.  In the end, your idea won't solve anything as you are not proposing a 2nd set of eyes to review and there is no assurances that the 2nd reviewer will do the job any better than the first one.  In order to really get a good sample size, you need dozens of reviews to get a reasonable consensus and that is impractical.

Comment: Why? The same impartial review is done with closing votes! And no one asked for dozens of reviews! I know that why my initial idea was to consider somehow the reputation of the reviewers for each post before removing it from the review queue.

Comment: Please note that I also suggest to add guidelines to mark as checked but it's quite similar to the other post, which I subscribe (and I didn't found it previously